# How to get VS Code to format blank line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've such kind of code in my angular app, and I'm wondering if there is a way to have some uniformity on the blank line:

```
async removeAdmin(user: User) {
    if (await this.checkCurrentUser(user)) {
      await this.userService.removeAdmin(user);
      this.toastr.success('User admin rights removed');
    }
  }

  async addAdmin(user: User) {


    if (await this.checkCurrentUser(user)) {
      await this.userService.addAdmin(user);
      this.toastr.success('User admin rights added');
    }

  }
  async checkCurrentUser(user: User): Promise<boolean> {

    if (await this.userService.isCurrentUser(user)) {
      this.toastr.error('Cannot change access of yourself');
      return false
    }

    
    return true
  }
```

When I format the code, I was kind of hopping to have:

- multiple consequent blank line reduced to one
- have one blank linke between each function

Is there a way to configure VS Code for that?

Comment: Have you looked into linting/formatting plugins for your language of choice? You can configure a 'auto-format on save'  option in vscode.

Comment: Have you tried something like `prettier` to format your code?

Comment: @ReyYoung No, I'm a bit new in this ecosystem. Should I take "Prettier" or "Prettier eslint"

Comment: @ReyYoung I tried to install prettier, but it seems concurrencing TSLINT(by exemple, TSLINT recomends me to put single quotes, which I like, and on save, prettier removes them).

Comment: @ReyYoung Turns out that prettier doesn't manage this: https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#empty-lines

Comment: @J4N that's a bummer.  When I try it prettier is able to remove consequent blank lines to one. But its unable to provide a gap between each function. May need plugin to do that. Cannot find any plugins to do the thing.

Comment: Bump, any solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73135328/how-to-automatically-delete-empty-lines-in-vs-code-when-formatting-on-c solves the point "multiple consequent blank line reduced to one"